# "Controller" is not registered angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, ngroute

I have created a new project, but got a problem which I am not able to fix.

Here's my example:

I have this error :

"Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'PostController' is not registered."

Connexion.html

```
<section id="login" ng-controller="PostController as postCtrl">
<div class="container center-bloc">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-wrap">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <img id="logo" style="max-width:100%;" src="img.png">

                </div>
                <h2 id="ResultConnexion"></h2>
                <form role="form" id="login-form" ng-submit="postCtrl.Search1()" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="userLogin" required autofocus ng-model="postCtrl.inputData.username" type="text" name="user" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="exemple@example.com">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="userPassword" required ng-model="postCtrl.inputData.password" type="password" name="mdp" id="key" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block" ng-disabled="login.$invalid" >Connexion</button>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorMsg">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
                            ×</button>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{errorMsg}}
                    </div>
                    <div></div>
                </form>
                <hr>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

index. js

```
'use strict';
var routeApp  = angular.module("routeApp", ["ngRoute"]);
routeApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl : "template/connexion.html",
        controller : "PostController"
    })

});






var routeAppControllers = angular.module('routeAppControllers',['ngRoute']);



routeAppControllers.controller('PostController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {


this.postForm = function() {



    var Pass = {"user":(this.inputData.username),"mdp":(this.inputData.Password)};

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/',
        data: Pass,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })

        .then(function(response) {


            if ( response.data.resultat == 0) {

                window.location.href = '/information';
                alert('hello')

            } else {
                $scope.errorMsg = 'Bad';
            }
        }, function(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        })
}

}]);
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate modules showing and neither is injected in the other.

Assuming your `ng-app` uses `routeApp` you need to inject `routeAppControllers` module into `routeApp` module

```
var routeApp = angular.module("routeApp", ["ngRoute", "routeAppControllers"]);
```

Also you only need to inject `ngRoute` once.

As noted in other answer you only use `ng-controller` when it is not declared in routing config also, or you end up with multiple controller instances

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove `ng-controller="PostController as postCtrl">` from template .Because you defined it in route . and also change to below.

```
  .when("/", {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl : "template/connexion.html",
    controller : "PostController as postCtrl"
})
```

another tip that recommended you declare `var vm = this` and use `vm` instead of `this`

```
    vm.postForm = function() {...}
```